# How best to define nullable integer customizable variables?

Tags: customize, variables, defcustom

I would like to define a variable using `defcustom` so that it can be customized by users of an emacs package.  The variable is an integer (let's call it `spam-override`), and its function is to override the value of another integer variable (`spam`).  `0` is an allowed value of both `spam` and `spam-override`.  If `spam-override` is set to `0`, that means "override with the value 0" rather than "do not override".  It seems natural to allow `spam-override` `nil` to indicate that the override is disabled.

I suspect that using `nil` in this way isn't how `defcustom` is best used for variables of this kind.

What's the best way to achieve this functionality?  For example, is it usually best to use a composite `defcustom` type by using the `choice` constructor, or to define an extra boolean variable, maybe named `override-spam` to indicate whether integer variable `spam-override` should be used?

Comment: Re-reading the docs again I guess I want `:type '(choice integer (const nil))` https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Composite-Types.html#Composite-Types

Comment: You can provide that as an answer to your own question. You can also accept that answer, if it solves your problem and you don't see a better answer posted. Having an accepted answer for a question can be helpful to other readers.

Comment: Whether to use one user option with multiple kinds of value or two options, each with a different kind of value, is a stylistic or usability choice. It depends what you think is most useful/usable by your users. Other things being equal, and unless the sets of allowable values are complex or confusable, having fewer options is often a good idea. In general here, there is no "best" in general; there is what you think is best for your use.

Comment: Hi Drew, I left it for somebody else to answer to see if others agreed about good style here.  My mutable opinion is that it's not just a matter of opinion: I think using `nil` in this particular case is better, if only because that's commonly used in emacs (and, less contingently, it reduces the problem of having a lot of variables to deal with).  I had a moment where I thought "maybe that's only commonly used for non-customizable variables" because I didn't see a way to do it that worked nicely with customize... but it works fine.

Comment: ...but I take your point there might well be other cases where a different choice is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've ascertained it correctly in your subsequent comment, but here's an example with labels for the options:

```
:type '(choice (integer :tag "Limit")
               (const :tag "Unlimited" nil))
```